# Removing @AppStorage objects using UserDefaults does not update SwiftUI view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have multiple `@AppStorage`-wrapped variables:

```
@AppStorage(Keys.test1.rawValue) var test1 = false
@AppStorage(Keys.test2.rawValue) var test2 = 0
@AppStorage(Keys.test3.rawValue) var test3 = 1.0
// ... Many more
```

And I wanted to reset them all to their default values without having to set them again one by one.

I added an extension to UserDefaults to reset the keys:

```
enum Keys: String, CaseIterable {
    case test1 = "TestKey1"
    case test2 = "TestKey2"
    case test3 = "TestKey3"
}

extension UserDefaults {
    func resetKeys(){
        Keys.allCases.forEach {
            removeObject(forKey: $0.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

But after resetting with `UserDefauls.standard.resetKeys()` it does reset but doesn't update the SwiftUI view at all, **unless I close the app and relaunch.**

Having a function that does it manually, updates the view instantly:

```
func resetKeys() {
     test1 = false
     test2 = 0
     test3 = 1.0
}
```

---

Entire Sample:

```
enum Keys: String, CaseIterable {
    case test1 = "TestKey1"
    case test2 = "TestKey2"
    case test3 = "TestKey3"
}

class SomeClass: ObservableObject {
    @AppStorage(Keys.test1.rawValue) var test1 = false
    @AppStorage(Keys.test2.rawValue) var test2 = 0
    @AppStorage(Keys.test3.rawValue) var test3 = 1.0
    // ... Many more
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var storage: SomeClass

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}

extension UserDefaults {
    func resetKeys(){
        Keys.allCases.forEach {
            removeObject(forKey: $0.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same issue. I have a backgroundRefreshTask that updates some values using UserDefaults. When the app resumes, the SwiftUI view that uses AppStorage is not seeing the new data. Any ideas?

Comment: @FlatDog Sadly no :(

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76343695/userdefaults-observableobject-and-swiftui/76343832#76343832 seems to be working for me.