SwiftUI App Not Persisting Images with @AppStorage and File System
I am building a SwiftUI app that allows users to add and view images, and I need to save these images so that they persist across app launches. I am using @AppStorage to store paths to the images saved in the app's documents directory. However, the images are not persisting after I close and reopen the app, and I can't figure out why.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
The images are displayed in a TabView.
Users can add images using an ImagePicker.
The saveImages() function saves the image paths to @AppStorage after converting them to a JSON string.
The loadImages() function loads the paths from @AppStorage, reads the images from disk, and populates the images array.
Relevant Code:
`@AppStorage("savedImagesPaths") var savedImagesData: Data = Data()  // Attempt to store paths
@State var images: [UIImage] = []

func saveImages() {
var imagePaths: [String] = []
for (index, image) in images.enumerated() {
    if let data = image.pngData() {
        let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("image_\(index).png")
        try? data.write(to: filename)
        imagePaths.append(filename.path)
    }
}

if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(imagePaths) {
    savedImagesData = data
}
}

func loadImages() {
 if let data = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: savedImagesData) {
    images = data.compactMap { path in
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)) {
            return UIImage(data: data)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
}`

Issue:
The images are not saved when the app is closed and reopened. I am unable to persist the image data across app launches.
The images do appear in the TabView after they are added, but they do not persist after relaunch.
The savedImagesData (which stores encoded image paths) is declared as Data, which might not be handled correctly by @AppStorage.
I am using @AppStorage to store the paths, but the approach seems to be failing.
Questions:
Why is the image data not being persisted correctly across app launches?
Is there a better approach for storing image paths persistently in SwiftUI?
Could there be an issue with how @AppStorage interacts with Data for storing arrays of strings?
Encoding the image paths into JSON using JSONEncoder and saving it as Data in @AppStorage.
Loading the image paths on onAppear to populate the images array.
Checking the documents directory manually to see if the images were saved, and they are indeed there, but loadImages() does not seem to populate the images array correctly.
I suspect that the issue lies either with how I am using @AppStorage with Data or with the encoding/decoding process of the paths. Any help or suggestions for better approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Your code works for me in my tests, the @AppStorage stores the data
and retrieves it on re-launch of the App.
Note however, you shoud give your images unique names, not using index in
getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("image_\(index).png").
Also you should use do{...}catch{print(error)} instead of try?.
Note also from the docs,
Persisting File References

App Storage is for RawRepresentable not Data

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76343695/userdefaults-observableobject-and-swiftui/76343832#76343832

Note, AppStorage/UserDefaults can cater for Data/NSData, see the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults#2926904
